# How can I use Apache Virtual Host in Google Drive with MAMP

Tags: macos, apache, google-drive-api, mamp

Editing my **local-development.conf** file, which I am able to make work with Dropbox but not Google Drive (because of spaces in the folder name, I think).

```
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/vhosts/">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# Named Virtual Host
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog /Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/logs/access.log vcommon
ErrorLog /Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/logs/errors.log
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/vhosts/%0
```

I have tried escaping:

```
CustomLog /Users/myusername/Google\ Drive/CODE\ PROJECTS/logs/access.log vcommon
ErrorLog /Users/myusername/Google\ Drive/CODE\ PROJECTS/logs/errors.log
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/myusername/Google\ Drive/CODE\ PROJECTS/vhosts/%0
```

Error log tells me that "Google\" is not a file.

So I tried quotes, making sure they are not curly quotes:

```
CustomLog "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/logs/access.log" vcommon
ErrorLog "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/logs/errors.log"
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/vhosts/"%0
```

I tried to make an alias on my Mac to both of these folders, but that did not solve the problem.

Obviously renaming Google Drive folder is not an option and I'd prefer to leave the other folder name intact as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include the %0 variable within the quotes.

```
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/vhosts/">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# Named Virtual Host
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/logs/access.log" vcommon
ErrorLog "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/logs/errors.log"
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Google Drive/CODE PROJECTS/vhosts/%0"
```